# Custom Elementor Widget Styling Issues: Front-End Styles Not Reflected in Elementor Editor - Assistance Needed

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, elementor, wordpress-plugin-creation

I've developed a custom carousel widget for Elementor using the Slick slider. On the website's front-end, everything looks and works as expected; the styling of the carousel is exactly how I want it. However, I'm encountering an issue when it comes to viewing and editing this widget within the Elementor editor itself. The styles applied to the front-end do not reflect in the Elementor editor, which is not only confusing from a design consistency standpoint but also limits the user's ability to see their modifications in real-time as they insert content into the widget's input fields.

I'm aiming for a seamless design experience where the widget's appearance in the Elementor editor mirrors its front-end display, including the immediate reflection of content updates made by the user. This would significantly improve the user interface and editing experience for those working with my custom widget.

**linked-carouselle.php:**

[enqueue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq7L8.png)

**widgets\carouselle-widget.php:**

[My class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7po5u.png)

[My controls pt.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMXM.png)

[My controls pt.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBkqs.png)

[Render function in my class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAAFz.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.